# Keras goes out of memory when running my toy examples

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, memory-leaks

I'm learning Keras after having worked in other frameworks for a while and I have the following code toy code example:

```
import keras.layers 
import keras.models 
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import random 
import os
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

TrainingDirectory="/home/thijser/host/ImageConverter/trainingdata" 
def main():
    model = define_feedforward_network1()
    compileModel(model)
    model.summary()
    train(model)

def define_feedforward_network1():
    inp = keras.engine.input_layer.Input(shape=(None,None,3))
    init = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)
    layer1=keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(inp)
    layer2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer1)
    outp = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=init)(layer2)

    return keras.Model(input=inp,output=outp)


def compileModel(model):
    adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam,
    metrics=["mse"])

def train(model):
    model.fit_generator(mygenerator(),steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=16)


def mygenerator():

    batch_features=None
    batch_labels=None
    while True:
        target=random.choice(os.listdir(TrainingDirectory))
        batch_features=cv2.imread(TrainingDirectory+'/'+target+"/input.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        batch_labels=cv2.imread(TrainingDirectory+'/'+target+"/labelcol.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        yield np.array([batch_features]), np.array([batch_labels])

main()
```

Which is a simple neural network for (in this case) turning color images into grayscale images (just to get a feel for this). It can be run by placing several folders into the trainingDirectory folder and placing 1 image called labelcol.png and the other input.jpg (same size as the first) inside each of these folders.

However when I run it it goes out of error rather quickly (right around the end of the first 16 images into training). If I turn on the report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom I get a segfault instead so that doesn't provide me with useful information, I can however see that the memory usage jumps by about 100-300 MB at a time suggesting that entire tensors might not be getting deallocated.

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the size of the images? You're only using Conv layers so running a 3000x3000x3 image, will produce 3000x3000x64 after first layer, 3000x3000x128 after second layer and so on. Try resing the images to 200x200 or something like that to see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can not load all your training images into your RAM. You will need to build a custom DataLoader that loads the images in batches in your training loop.

This [article](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) has a great tutorial that helped me a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't the mygenerator() function already take care of that?